Viability of using Adversial Neural Networks trained against top performing chess engines to induce suboptimal moves
I'm a third year computing student considering undertaking the project, as specified in the title, for my dissertation. The goal wouldn't be to create an engine capable of beating the likes of stockfish in a complete start to finish game but to try and cause it to choose suboptimal moves in smaller isolated situations by specifically training using an Adversarial Neural Network. I'm aware this has been attempted before in the Antifish project back in 2018 but to my understanding this was before top chess engines were using Neural Network based decision making.
Please can anybody smarter than me advise on whether this is worth looking any further into or if it's too ambitious/infeasible.

https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/40912/has-any-researcher-tried-adversarial-examples-against-chess-engines Does this answer your question?
